# Атрибут value у input

Tags: javascript, html

Возможно ли использовать два значения в атрибуте value у тега input?
Если да, то возможно ли их парсить отдельно друг от друга с помощью js?

Это нужно для того, чтобы одно значение уходило в заявке на почту, а другое использовалось в калькуляторе. Может есть какой то более разумный способ это сделать?

Такое написание кстати вообще приемлемо?:

```html
<div class="form__block">
  <input id="where2" type="radio" name="Когда приступить" value="10days 6000">
  <label for="where2"> В течении 10 дней</label>
</div>
```

Comment: > _Может есть какой то более разумный способ это сделать?_ Сделать два инпута?))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Возможно ли использовать два значения в атрибуте value у тега input?

Да, возможно, `value1<delimiter>value2`.

```
value="value1|value2"
```

> Если да, то возможно ли их парсить отдельно друг от друга с помощью js?

Более приемлемый вариан атрубит `data-*`, показываете `value`, обрабатываете `data-value`.

Вот пример:

```js
var inpt = document.querySelector('#where2')

console.info(inpt.value);
console.info(inpt.getAttribute('data-value'));
```

```html
<div class="form__block">
  <input id="where2" type="radio" name="Когда приступить" value="10days 6000" data-value="10,6000">
  <label for="where2"> В течении 10 дней</label>
</div>
```

---

[Доки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае `value` это строка, которая может быть любого вида. Поэтому никто не мешает вам делать с ней, все что вздумается:

```
<div class="form__block">
  <input id="nums" name="Цифры" value="1,2,3,4,5">
</div>
```

Обработать можно так:

```
const values = nums.value.split(',').map(parseInt); // массив чисел
console.log(values.map(x => x * x )); // квадраты чисел
```

В вашем случае, можете разбить строку по пробелам `split(' ')` и тогда у вас будет массив значений, которые можете отправлять куда угодно

Answer (score 1):

Есть вариант использовать для этого `data-атрибуты`:

```js
var el = $('#where2');
console.log(el.val());
console.log(el.attr('data-value'));
```

```html
<div class="form__block">
  <input id="where2" type="radio" name="Когда приступить" value="10days" data-value="6000">
  <label for="where2"> В течении 10 дней</label>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: тогда уж `element.dataset.value` или `el.data("value")`

Comment: Первый вариант не сработает, второй да.
Вообще про разницу можно почитать [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18844822/6677992). Если в двух словах `el.data("value")` не позволит вам установить значение у элемента, а `el.attr('data-value')` может работать только со строками.